# Скрыть div?

Tags: html, классы, css

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6frj/
Привет!
Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы она закрывалась только если кликнуть на buttons, вместо того чтобы скрывалась когда кликаю в любом месте.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
$('.facttext').click(function (e) {
    var $buttons = $('.buttons');

    if ($buttons.css('display') != 'block') {
        $buttons.show();

        var firstClick = false;
        $(".facttext").bind('click.myEvent', function (e) {
            if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest('.buttons').length == 0) {
                $buttons.hide();
                $(".facttext").unbind('click.myEvent');
            }
            firstClick = false;
        });
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!! все работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

Немного переделал ваш скрипт:

```
$(function() {
    $('.facttext').click(function(e) {
        var $buttons = $(this).next('.buttons');
        if ($buttons.css('display') != 'block') {
            $buttons.show();
        } else {
            $buttons.hide();
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: А если ещё красивее делать, то всё ваше условий, вместе с созданием переменной, можно заменить готовым методом `.toggle()`:

 $(function(){
     $('.facttext').click(function(e) {
         $(this).next('.buttons').toggle()
         e.preventDefault();
     });
 });